# Making my ajax updated div fade in

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code that performs an ajax call and loads the results into two duplicate divs every time a dropdown is changed. I want the results to be faded into the div, to give a more obvious indication that something has changed, as its so seamless its sometimes hard to notice the change!

```
print("$('.ajaxdropdown').change(function(){


        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/includes/html/gsm-tariff.php",
            data: "c_name="+escape($(this).val()),
            success: function(html){
                $("#charges-gsm").html(html);
                                    //i want to fade result into these 2 divs...
                $("#charges-gsm-faq").html(html);
                $("#charges-gsm-prices").html(html);
            }
        });
    });");
```

I've tried appending the fadein method and a few other things, but no joy.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You'll have to `hide()` it before you can use `fadeIn()`.

**UPDATE:** Here's how you'd do this by chaining:

```
$("#charges-gsm-faq").hide().html(html).fadeIn();
$("#charges-gsm-prices").hide().html(html).fadeIn();
```

Comment: so is there a shorter way of doing it than this using chaining or something?
$("#charges-gsm-faq, #charges-gsm-prices").hide();
$("#charges-gsm-faq, #charges-gsm-prices").html(html);
$("#charges-gsm-faq, #charges-gsm-prices").fadein(slow);

Answer (score 4):

You could also leave it visible and just make it transparent, and then fade it to full opacity, using:

```
... .css({ opacity: 0 }).fadeTo("normal",1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to hide() it before you can use fadeIn()

Above worked for me

Answer (score 1):

It works with load():

```
$('.element').load('file.html').hide().fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery.ui has a bunch of different things you can do with effects.  You can find them here: http://docs.jquery.com/Effects