# Refresh comments section

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have put together a JQuery script that when entering a comment, it goes to a database and pulls the result back and displays it on the page. This works well, however I need a seperate page with just the comments on, which auto refreshes the results every 5 seconds (instead of clicking refresh on the browser). What I would also like is for the comments to FadeIn. I have tried to do this with resources I have found online, but most of them seem to keep replicating my content as well as refreshing.

Can you help?
[image]

**Comments.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="comments.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Live Comments</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="leaveComment">
  <h2>Leave a Comment</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Your Name:</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Comment:</label>
    <textarea cols="10" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button id="add">Add</button>
</div>
<div id="comments">
  <h2>Live Comments</h2>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                //retrieve comments to display on page
                $.getJSON("comments.php?jsoncallback=?", function(data) {

                    //loop through all items in the JSON array
                    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {

                        //create a container for each comment
                        var div = $("<div>").addClass("row").appendTo("#comments");

                        //add author name and comment to container
                        $("<label>").text(data[x].name).appendTo(div);
                        $("<div>").addClass("comment").text(data[x].comment).appendTo(div);
                    }
                }); 
                //add click handler for button
                $("#add").click(function() {

                    //define ajax config object
                    var ajaxOpts = {
                        type: "post",
                        url: "addComment.php",
                        data: "&author=" + $("#leaveComment").find("input").val() + "&comment=" + $("#leaveComment").find("textarea").val(),
                        success: function(data) {

                            //create a container for the new comment
                            var div = $("<div>").addClass("row").appendTo("#comments"); 

                            //add author name and comment to container
                            $("<label>").text($("#leaveComment").find("input").val()).appendTo(div);
                            $("<div>").addClass("comment").text($("#leaveComment").find("textarea").val()).appendTo(div).hide().fadeIn("slow");

                            //empty inputs
                            $("#leaveComment").find("input").val("");
                            $("#leaveComment").find("textarea").val("");
                        }
                    };

                    $.ajax(ajaxOpts);

                });     
            });     
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Moderator.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="comments.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="comments">
  <h2>Live Comments</h2>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                //retrieve comments to display on page
                $.getJSON("comments.php?jsoncallback=?", function(data) {

                    //loop through all items in the JSON array
                    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {

                        //create a container for each comment
                        var div = $("<div>").addClass("row").appendTo("#comments");

                        //add author name and comment to container
                        $("<label>").text(data[x].name).appendTo(div);
                        $("<div>").addClass("comment").text(data[x].comment).appendTo(div);
                    }
                }); 
                //add click handler for button
                $("#add").click(function() {

                    //define ajax config object
                    var ajaxOpts = {
                        type: "post",
                        url: "addComment.php",
                        data: "&author=" + $("#leaveComment").find("input").val() + "&comment=" + $("#leaveComment").find("textarea").val(),
                        success: function(data) {

                            //create a container for the new comment
                            var div = $("<div>").addClass("row").appendTo("#comments"); 

                            //add author name and comment to container
                            $("<label>").text($("#leaveComment").find("input").val()).appendTo(div);
                            $("<div>").addClass("comment").text($("#leaveComment").find("textarea").val()).appendTo(div).hide().fadeIn("slow");

                            //empty inputs
                            $("#leaveComment").find("input").val("");
                            $("#leaveComment").find("textarea").val("");
                        }
                    };

                    $.ajax(ajaxOpts);

                });     
            });     
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Comments.php**

```
<?php

    //db connection detils
    $host = "localhost";
  $user = "CommentsDB";
  $password = "password";
  $database = "comments";

    //make connection
  $server = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
  $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

    //query the database
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments");

    //loop through and return results
  for ($x = 0, $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query); $x < $numrows; $x++) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

        $comments[$x] = array("name" => $row["name"], "comment" => $row["comment"]);        
    }

    //echo JSON to page
    $response = $_GET["jsoncallback"] . "(" . json_encode($comments) . ")";
    echo $response;

?>
```

**addComments.php**

```
<?php

  //db connection detils
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "CommentsDB";
  $password = "password";
  $database = "comments";

  //make connection
  $server = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
  $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

  //get POST data
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["author"]);
  $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["comment"]);

  //add new comment to database
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments VALUES(' $name ',' $comment ')");

?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did you expect? What did not work as you expected it?

Comment: you want something like comments on facebook?

Comment: I've tried a number of different ways to refresh things like:  var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
     $('#comment').load('moderator.html').fadeIn("slow");
}, 5000);

Comment: Why did you close my question!?

Answer (score 2):

> **QUOTE:** auto refreshes the results every 5 seconds

use this code.

```
function checkForComments() {}

$(document).ready(function () {
  //Wait 5 seconds then call checkForComments();
  setInterval("checkForComments()", 5000);
});
```

5000 here is time in milliseconds equivalent to 5 seconds.

---

> **QUOTE:**  but most of them seem to keep replicating my content as well as refreshing.

It isn't clear from your question what exactly does comments.php output. If it outputs all the comments in the database best option would be to keep an **array of the ids of the comments** that **have been posted** to page. Just write a **function** in JavaScript that **checks** if a **particular id exists** in that array and **append it if it doesn't**.

---

> **QUOTE:** What I would also like is for the comments to FadeIn

follow this question
[Making my ajax updated div fade in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183638/making-my-ajax-updated-div-fade-in)

**UPDATED**

**JavaScript to load comments**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //stores the comment IDs
    var comments=new Array();
    var count=1 ;
    function checkForComments() {
        $.getJSON("comments.php", addComments);
    }
    function addComments(data) {
        //loop through all items in the JSON array
        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
            alert(data[x].id);
            if(jQuery.inArray(data[x].id, comments)==-1){
                comments[count] = data[x].id;
                //create a container for each comment
                var div = $("<div>").addClass("row").appendTo("#comments");
                //add author name and comment to container
                $("<label>").text(data[x].name).appendTo(div);
                $("<div>").addClass("comment").text(data[x].comment).appendTo(div);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }


    $(document).ready(function () {
        checkForComments();
        setInterval("checkForComments()", 5000);
    });
</script>
```

**my comments.php**

```
<?php
//make connection
$server = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
$connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

//query the database
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments");

//loop through and return results
for ($x = 0, $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query); $x < $numrows; $x++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    //I have added ID here, 
    $comments[$x] = array("id" => $row["id"], "name" => $row["name"], "comment"
        => $row["comment"]);
}

echo json_encode($comments);
?>
```

**SQL for comments table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Comment: I'll add the comments.php to my question above. If you could help with the code I would be very greatful, as I can't really code this stuff I've just mashed code together ;)

Comment: Ok. When the comments page loads, does it show any comments? or are the comments added to the page using js after the page loads.

Comment: For the comments.html page the comments are populated automatically, with the moderator.html page the comments only populate once the page refreshes.

Comment: The code you have put doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I have added a working example try it.

Comment: Do I need to add a new column to my DB called "id" if so what type should I set it to etc?

Comment: yes there should be a column **'id'** of type **INT** and set to **autoincrement** I have also added the SQL to my post above.

Comment: I've added the id and it is showing up in the databse, however your load comments code isnt working on my moderator page?

Comment: I've updated my comments.php code above to the code you gave me. Now the results don't talk to the DB...

Comment: truncate the table and add new comments. Make sure ID doesn't have a null value

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this how would I "truncate" the table?

Comment: Ok. Truncate means deleting all the data in the table. SQL syntax is TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;

Comment: or simply delete all the rows in the table

Comment: I have cleared the rows, but the script now doesnt write to the DB any longer...

Comment: Post the structure of the table comment and the code for addComments.php

Comment: I have updated my original post with all of my code and files. I reverted back to my original code and this isn't working now either...

Comment: When working with databases always try to add some method to track errors for this script.......
`$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments VALUES(' $name ',' $comment ')");`
`if(!$result){ die('Error Occured: '. mysql_error());}`

Comment: and for the problem you are having ..Update the INSERT SQL Query to..

`INSERT INTO comments (name, comment ) VALUES(' $name ',' $comment ')`

Comment: That works great, now they have Id's and it calls the database etc. now how do I get the moderator.html page to call new comments without having to refresh the page? thanks for the help!

Comment: The JavaScript code for loading the comments can be used for moderation page as well.

Comment: if you haven't noticed the comments show up on the users page without refreshing.

Comment: where in the code should I add: function checkForComments() {}

$(document).ready(function () {
  //Wait 5 seconds then call checkForComments();
  setInterval("checkForComments()", 5000);
});

Comment: Yes it does for the page where there is the form, on the moderators page tehre is no form just the comments.

Comment: Thanks for all the help in this matter, I have scrapped the project as it is clear it is beyond my basic coding skills.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices: After adding `append()`ing the new content, remove the old content.

Or, set a "placeholder" element, and use .html() on it - that way you replace the old content, you don't add more.

Comment: I don't want to remove the old comments, I just need a auto refresh on the moderator page so they "moderator" doesn't need to keep reloading his browser to see the new comments as they are being added to the comments.html page

Comment: I didn't say to remove the old comments, I said to remove the old content. Then you replace it with the new content (which includes all the comments).